# Convert wallet address on Tron

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, web3js, tron

I need to get the wallet address from the trc-20 transaction  on the Trone network.

I found out that this info can be taken from the input field. I use web3.js to parse this field and get an address like

```
0xee564858c4874cac2d1fff98c1eabba915f50b2f
```

But I need it to be like

```
TXhRBjb8GDnodu3VY6vgmNXcGnLpQhm9NW
```

I can't find the info how to convert it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**tronWeb.address.toHex :**
Convert Base58 format addresses to Hex

```js
const convertedAddress = tronWeb.address.toHex(givenAddress);
```

**tronWeb.address.fromHex :**
Convert Hexstring format address to Base58 format address

```js
const convertedAddress = tronWeb.address.fromHex(givenAddress);
```

**tronWeb.address.fromPrivateKey :**
Derive its corresponding address based on the private key

```js
const givenAddress = tronWeb.address.fromPrivateKey(privateKey);
```

source [link](https://developers.tron.network/reference/address)